# Why using concurrent.futures in Python and BS4 is not optimize my running time?

Tags: python, web-scraping, optimization, beautifulsoup

I'm a beginner in Python and concurrent futures. I'm trying this piece of code :

```
#Importing Librairies 
import concurrent.futures
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#Def functions 
def page_builder(amount): 
    global page_list
    for i in range(1, amount):
        url = 'https://quotes.toscrape.com/page/' + str(i) + '/'
        page_list.append(url)
    
    print('---- URL LIST SUCCESSFULLY CREATED ----')


def get_url(data):
    global url_list
    global page_list
    try : 
        for url in data:
            r = requests.get(str(url))
            soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
            titles = soup.find_all("small", {"class": "author"})
            for title in titles:
                url_list.append(title.text)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Issue is -->      " + e)

page_builder(10)

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor :
    executor.map(get_url, (page_list))

print(url_list)

#Output --> url_list = []
```

I already tried to use get_url(page_list) alone and it's worked, I also use submit instead of 'executor.map' and it's also worked but it's not optimize my running time.

Mac OS BigSur - Python 3.9.5

Do you have any hints ?

Thanks a lot,

Julien

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it's just because I have to to give the opportunity to Threads to input himself the urls like this :

```
def get_url(data):
    global url_list
    global page_list
    try : 
        r = requests.get(str(data))
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
        titles = soup.find_all("small", {"class": "author"})
        for title in titles:
            url_list.append(title.text)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Issue is -->      " + e)

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor :
    executor.map(get_url, (page_list))

print(page_list)
```

Hope this can help somebody,

Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your function `get_url` is now being passed *a single URL*, not a list of URLs. I would also have that function return the list of titles it finds back to the main thread for accumulating into the list of titles being built and I would use a better choice of names for some of my variables and arguments. Finally, there are some coding optimizations you could make, such as using list comprehensions and `requests.Session` instance for doing your `get` requests.

```py
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def url_list_builder(num_pages):
    url_list = [f'https://quotes.toscrape.com/page/{i}/' for i in range(1, num_pages+1)]
    print('---- URL LIST SUCCESSFULLY CREATED ----')
    return url_list

# Use a Session instance:
session = requests.Session()

def get_url(url):
    try:
        r = session.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
        titles = soup.find_all("small", {"class": "author"})
        return [title.text for title in titles]
    except Exception as e:
        print("Issue is -->" + e)
        return [] # return empty list

url_list = url_list_builder(10)
titles = []
# Create pool size equal to number of URLs to be retrieved:
with ThreadPoolExecutor(len(url_list)) as executor:
    for title_list in executor.map(get_url, url_list):
        titles.extend(title_list)
print(titles)
```

Prints:

```
---- URL LIST SUCCESSFULLY CREATED ----
['Albert Einstein', 'J.K. Rowling', 'Albert Einstein', 'Jane Austen', 'Marilyn Monroe', 'Albert Einstein', 'André Gide', 'Thomas A. Edison', 'Eleanor Roosevelt', 'Steve Martin', 'Marilyn Monroe', 'J.K. Rowling', 'Albert Einstein', 'Bob Marley', 'Dr. Seuss', 'Douglas Adams', 'Elie Wiesel', 'Friedrich Nietzsche', 'Mark Twain', 'Allen Saunders', 'Pablo Neruda', 'Ralph Waldo Emerson', 'Mother Teresa', 'Garrison Keillor', 'Jim Henson', 'Dr. Seuss', 'Albert Einstein', 'J.K. Rowling', 'Albert Einstein', 'Bob Marley', 'Dr. Seuss', 'J.K. Rowling', 'Bob Marley', 'Mother Teresa', 'J.K. Rowling', 'Charles M. Schulz', 'William Nicholson', 'Albert Einstein', 'Jorge Luis Borges', 'George Eliot', 'George R.R. Martin', 'C.S. Lewis', 'Marilyn Monroe', 'Marilyn Monroe', 'Albert Einstein', 'Marilyn Monroe', 'Marilyn Monroe', 'Martin Luther King Jr.', 'J.K. Rowling', 'James Baldwin', 'Jane Austen', 'Eleanor Roosevelt', 'Marilyn Monroe', 'Albert Einstein', 'Haruki Murakami', 'Alexandre Dumas fils', 'Stephenie Meyer', 'Ernest Hemingway', 'Helen Keller', 'George Bernard Shaw', 'Charles Bukowski', 'Suzanne Collins', 'Suzanne Collins', 'C.S. Lewis', 'J.R.R. Tolkien', 'J.K. Rowling', 'Ernest Hemingway', 'Ralph Waldo Emerson', 'Mark Twain', 'Dr. Seuss', 'Alfred Tennyson', 'Charles Bukowski', 'Terry Pratchett', 'Dr. Seuss', 'J.D. Salinger', 'George Carlin', 'John Lennon', 'W.C. Fields', 'Ayn Rand', 'Mark Twain', 'Albert Einstein', 'Jane Austen', 'J.K. Rowling', 'Jane Austen', 'Jane Austen', 'C.S. Lewis', 'C.S. Lewis', 'Mark Twain', 'Mark Twain', 'C.S. Lewis', 'J.K. Rowling', 'Jimi Hendrix', 'J.M. Barrie', 'E.E. Cummings', 'Khaled Hosseini', 'Harper Lee', "Madeleine L'Engle", 'Mark Twain', 'Dr. Seuss', 'George R.R. Martin']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering !

Answer (score 0):

I see a significant performance gain using `concurrent.futures`.

Also avoid using `global` variables. You can just pass the lists to the functions instead.

I have used `time` module to show the time taken by the script - **With Threads** and **Without Threads**

Here is the complete code:

```
#Importing Librairies 
import requests
import time
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#Def functions 
def page_builder(amount, page_list): 
    for i in range(1, amount):
        url = 'https://quotes.toscrape.com/page/' + str(i) + '/'
        page_list.append(url)
    
    print('---- URL LIST SUCCESSFULLY CREATED ----')


def get_url(url):
    url_list = []
    
    try : 
        r = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
        titles = soup.find_all("small", {"class": "author"})
        for title in titles:
            url_list.append(title.text)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Issue is: " + str(e))

    return url_list



#######################################
# Without Threads
#######################################

start = time.perf_counter()
page_list = []
page_builder(10, page_list)
author_list = []
for i in page_list:
    author_list += get_url(i)
finish = time.perf_counter()
print(f'Author_list entries: {len(author_list)}')
print(f'Time taken without threads: {round(finish-start,2)} second(s).')


#######################################
# With Threads
#######################################
start1 = time.perf_counter()
page_list = []
page_builder(10, page_list)
author_list = []
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor :
    for res in executor.map(get_url, page_list):
        author_list += res

finish1 = time.perf_counter()
print(f'Author_list entries: {len(author_list)}')
print(f'Time taken with threads: {round(finish1-start1,2)} second(s).')
```

```
Author_list entries: 90
Time taken without threads: 10.4 second(s).

Author_list entries: 90
Time taken with threads: 2.59 second(s).
```